# Facebook app not showing in FB group app store

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook business app that I use for Facebook social login, which works fine.

Now I want to add the same app to my Facebook group (I'm an admin of the group), which should allow me to use the Facebook graph API to post to my group. However when I go to add the app in my Facebook group, my app doesn't show in the list of available apps in the Facebook group app store. How do I get my app listed in the Facebook group app store so I can add my app to my Facebook group?

Comment: Did you get your app reviewed & approved for the use of the Groups API feature yet? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/groups-api

Comment: Thanks CBroe. The app review page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/ states:"If your app will be used by anyone without a Role on the app or a role in a Business that has claimed the app, it must first undergo App Review."  My app is not meant to be used by anyone else apart from me so I interpreted this as saying my app doesn't need to be reviewed.

Comment: That mainly applies to testing features that only affect those users. But I am pretty sure that you won't be able to post into a group with a live app, without getting this feature approved in review first.

Comment: Hello, @Torsten 

Did you make it works? What did you do to show your app to the list? or to post?

Comment: I didn't get it to work. I think @CBroe is probably right that you have to get the app reviewed but FB do seem the change their rules quite a bit so you'll need to check the latest FB docs for details. Good luck!